# How can I create an array of only "odd" numbers between 1 and n - Java?

Tags: java

I ran into an issue I can't seem to solve, and all the searches I do are not completely relevant to the issue I am having, and trying to implement those things to solve my issue still doesn't work. I've spent an hour trying to find another question or post somewhere that would help but can't seem to find any specific to my issue (unless Google just doesn't want to work today).

I am trying to create a method that returns an array of all of the odd numbers between 1 and n, say in this example 1 to 255.
I tried the following (here is the method currently):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BasicJava: { 
    public Integer[] arrayOfOdds() {
        
        int n = 255;
        Integer[] odds = new Integer[(n+1)/2];
        for(int i = 1; i < n+1; i+=2) {
            
            odds[i/2] = i;
        }
        
        return odds;
    }
}
```

Main Method:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BasicJavaTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BasicJava test = new BasicJava();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test.arrayOfOdds()));
    }

}
```

I tried using an array to do the same thing before switching to using an `ArrayList` (I like other data structures more than I do arrays) and converting to an array and got the same output (I will just put part of the output array to not use too much space):

```
[0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 9, 0, 11, 0, 13, 0, 15, 0, 17, 0, 19, 0, 21, 0, 23, 0, 25, 0, 27, 0, 29, 0, 31, 0]
```

What do I need to resolve this issue?

If I just wanted to print all of the odds between 1 and N using the same for loop and if statement, I would get the correct output.

Thank you

Comment: An update, I tried this with both C# and JavaScript so far and had no issues. Just tried python as well, worked without issues there.

Comment: Could you show the complete code that you use to test the array contents? I can't reproduce this problem and can't see any reason why it would occur.

Comment: The main thing is I am wanting the method to return a full array, then the array itself will be printed in the test file the way this challenge wants it.
`public Integer[] arrayOfOdds() {
        //ArrayList<Integer> odds = new ArrayList<>();
        int n = 255;
        Integer[] odds = new Integer[(n+1)/2];
        for(int i = 1; i < n+1; i+=2) {
            //odds.add(i);
            odds[i/2] += i;
        }
        /* Integer[] res = new Integer[odds.size()];
        res = odds.toArray(res); */
        return odds;
    }`

Comment: In the main method in the test file this is how they want it called 

`System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test.arrayOfOdds()));`

I just saw what I did wrong, I feel like an idiot some times. it's the odds[] += when it should just be =.  Actually, the issue still exists. (With the solution I posted above)*

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your code?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: The one thing that sometimes annoys me about running into issues like this is, if I try the same thing in any other language I know, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this is linear time complexity and without using an ArrayList.

Your final output will always have n/2 elements so your array size can be fixed at the same. In the next step you can simply populate the values in your array.

FYR code:

```
int[] arr = new int[((n+1)/2)];
for(int i = 0, e = 1; i < arr.length; e += 2, i++) {
    arr[i] = e;
}
```

Comment: Could do this without extra variable, space optimization as well :)

Comment: Yeah, both ways it will be still constant amount of auxiliary space

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IntStream` like this.

```
static int[] arrayOfOdds() {
    return IntStream.iterate(1, i -> i + 2)
        .takeWhile(i -> i < 256)
        .toArray();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayOfOdds()));
}
```

output:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, ... , 251, 253, 255]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int N = 255;
    Integer[] array = new Integer[(N+1)/2];
    for (int j = 1; j < N+1; j+=2) {
        array[j/2] = j;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Comment: still running into the same issue for some odd reason (no pun intended). Could there be something wrong with VS Code? Both your solution and the one below should work. I am going to use an online compiler to just see if it's a local issue.

Comment: Please share the issue

Comment: I get output that looks like [0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 9, 0, 11, 0, 13, 0, 15, 0, 17, 0, 19]

Comment: The output looks OK in my console.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to add condition to check for each integer.

Here is a simple trick to create odds number:

Start with 1 and increase 2 for next element. ( 1,3,5...)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> arr = getOddList(255);
    System.out.print(arr);
  }

  private static List<Integer> getOddList(int n) {
    List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i = i + 2) {
      nums.add(i);
    }
    return nums;
  }
```

//Output [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11...

Comment: I still ran into the same issue when trying to create and return an array. Even if I just put an array up top instead of an ArrayList I still get the 0,1,0,2,0,3 issue.

Comment: Please try again with my update code...